# Efficient way to Find if points form a Square. Calculation C++

Tags: c++, math, shapes, coordinate-systems

I'm new here. I'm solving a problem to check if N points (x,y) form a square. The final output is the number of squares the points can form + the biggest area (one of the squares).
Input like this:

```
6
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 2
2 1
```

Output:

```
2 -> (2 Squares were formed)
1 -> (1 was the biggest area)
```

[image]

So I'm reading the x and y like this:

```
cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin >> coordenadas[i].x >> coordenadas[i].y;concat[i]=coordenadas[i].y * 100000 + coordenadas[i].x;}
    sort (concat, concat+n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        A.x=coordenadas[i].x;A.y=coordenadas[i].y;
        for(int ii=M;ii<n;ii++)
        {
            B.x=coordenadas[ii].x;
            B.y=coordenadas[ii].y;
            ...
            calculo();
            if(mArea<area)
            mArea=area;
        }
        M+=1;
    }
```

In the next function, i'm trying to calculate a x and y var to get the values like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqtau.png

But i'm not sure about my calculation.

And my calculo function:

```
void calculo()
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    if(A.x==B.x)
    {
        x=abs(B.y-A.y);
        area=x*x;
        R1.c1=(B.y) * 100000 + (A.x + x);
        R1.c2=(B.y) * 100000 + (A.x - x);
        if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, R1.c1))
        if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, R1.c2))
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;
    }
    else
    {
        x=abs(B.y-A.y);
        y=abs(B.x-A.x);
        area=sqrt(x*x+y*y)*sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        R1.c1=(B.y + y) * 100000 + (B.x - x);
        R1.c2=(A.y + y) * 100000 + (A.x - x);
        if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, R1.c1))
        if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, R1.c2))
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is, pick 2 unique points and calculate the possible other two points that form a square. then I "concat" them into a unique integer (eg. (B.y + y) * 100000 + (B.x - x) wich means -> y * 100000 +x) then i look for them with a binary search, if they were found i increment the n_square var.

The problem is, I'm not sure if the calculation is ok, and I need a hand with this. I know that there is a way to calculate with bitset but I'm not an expert so i can't use bitset. I'm trying to get a O(N^2 * log(V)) solution. Give me some tips

***################### NEW EDIT AFTER SOME COMMENTS -> ###################***

NEW Input (Comment)

```
9
5 3
1 4
1 3
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 4
3 2
4 2
```

Output:

```
6 (Number of Squares)
0 (Its Area-> I'm not calculating yet)
```

Expected Output

```
3
5 (Area)
```

New Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct c{

    int x,y;

}A,B,C,D,coordenadas[3001];

int quadrados=0,n=0;
long int area;
long int concat[3001];

int dist2 (c A,c B) {
  int x = A.x - B.x;
  int y = A.y - B.y;
  return x*x + y*y;
}



void calculo()
{
    int d = dist2(A, B);
    const int x = B.x - A.x;
    const int y = B.y - A.y;
    C.x = A.x - y;
    C.y = A.y + x;
    D.x = B.x - y;
    D.y = B.y + x;
    d = dist2(A, B);
    if (dist2(A, C) == d && 2*d == dist2(B, C))
    if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, C.y * 100000 + C.x))
    if (dist2(B, D) == d && dist2(C, D) == d)
    if (binary_search (concat, concat+n, D.y * 100000 + D.x))
    {
        quadrados+=1;
    }

}

int main() {

    int M=1,mArea=0;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin >> coordenadas[i].x >> coordenadas[i].y;concat[i]=coordenadas[i].y * 100000 + coordenadas[i].x;}
    sort (concat, concat+n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        A.x=coordenadas[i].x;
        A.y=coordenadas[i].y;
        for(int ii=M;ii<n;ii++)
        {
            B.x=coordenadas[ii].x;
            B.y=coordenadas[ii].y;
            calculo();
            if(mArea<area)
            mArea=area;
        }
        M+=1;
    }

    if(quadrados==0)
    cout << quadrados << endl;
    else
    cout << quadrados << endl << mArea << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the maximum size of the grid (if any), or is it always 4x4 as in your example?

Comment: Is a example. N < 3000 and x,y < 20000

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated that all point are on a grid.

Comment: What about squares that are rotated? Do they count?

Comment: All them count . Also, just positive coordinates are alowed

Comment: Please post the output of your code as well.

Comment: I added the output @QuestionC

Answer (score 2):

From your picture:

```
const int x = B.x - A.x;
const int y = B.y - A.y;
C.x = A.x - y;
C.y = A.y + x;
D.x = B.x - y;
D.y = B.y + x;
```

then

```
area = x * x + y * y;
```

Comment: It works with all points or just when A and B are in the position of the image?

Comment: For all relative positions (in plan) between `A` and `B`.

Comment: We have `BD = z ^ AB` (with `^` the cross product, `z` the unit vector orthogonal to the plan).

Comment: Yes, just test it: `A.x == B.x`, you got `x == 0`, `C.y = A.y` and `D.y = B.y` and `C.x == D.x == A.x - y == B.x - y`

Comment: There is a second possible square using A and B, by forming C and D with `+y` and `-x` instead of `-y` and `+x`. It's the symmetric square by the line (AB) of the square you defined.

Comment: It's not calculating well using your sugestion. Look to the new input i put on the topic. Using your calculation, it calculates 6 squares instead of 3, (the area is ok). Other simple test is: Look at http://i.imgur.com/Xiq87DQ.png . Look the blue square. N=4 -> (2,1)(1,2)(2,3)(3,2). With your suggestion it gives 1 square -> Right! but the area will be 2! which is not.

Comment: I also added the full code solution, probabily is better to check something

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Xiq87DQ.png -> Plus, Is the all possible square rotations that can be formed with (x,y)

Comment: @Cimbali: CW or CCW square from AB are possible.

Comment: @NewYear: The area of given example should be `2` (`(-1 * -1)*(1 * 1)`).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry you are right. Pitagoras. I have to test it better

Comment: But still calculates more squares. It should output 3 and its presenting 6, know why?

Comment: Depending of order with  `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, but you may check `AB`, `BC`, `CD` and so have duplicate squares... A solution is to use `AB` as diagonal and divide square number by 2 at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume that all coordinates are integers and your chosen type can fit twice the square of the largest coordinate (800 million, in your case -- not hard). The latter assumption can be dispensed with, if needed, but the former isn't so easy since you'd otherwise have to decide how to handle rounding.

The basic idea is to loop through each point A and each point B appearing later in the list than A. Compute

```
int dist2 (A, B) {
  int x = A.x - B.x;
  int y = A.y - B.y;
  return x*x + y*y;
}

int d = dist2(A, B);
```

so that `d` is the squared distance between A and B. Now define

```
c C1, C2, D;
C1.x = 2*A.x - B.y;
C1.y = B.x;
C2.x = B.y;
C2.y = 2*A.y - B.x;
```

and check if C1 (resp., C2) is on the list following B. If so, call it C and check if

```
dist2(B, D) == d && dist2(C, D) == d
```

If so, ABCD is a square. If you have n elements in total the first two loops happen n(n-1)/2 times and each pair causes 2 or 3 lookups, showing that the algorithm runs in time O(n^2 log n).

Edit: An earlier version also gave a simpler algorithm which ran in time O(n^3). Its existence caused confusion so I removed it and made the other algorithm more explicit.

Comment: I have to consider that C and D are like the last answer?
      ## const int x = B.x - A.x; ## const int y = B.y - A.y;
C.x = A.x - y; ## 
C.y = A.y + x; ## 
D.x = B.x - y; ## 
D.y = B.y + x; ##


How its the calculation for C AND D to check later if is square? (using your function)

Comment: In the first method, you just have four nested loops which give you A, B, C, and D. In the second you compute two different possibilities for C and try each one (and then compute D, if C exists in your list).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2ztg28Z.png -> I'm doing like this. The problem is that its counting to much squares. If i use the last input in my topic (I edited) it should be just 3 squares because: http://i.imgur.com/Xiq87DQ.png And not 6 (it counts 6)

Comment: @NewYear: Well, you're not using the method I gave, so I can suggest only a general tip: print the points A, B, C, and D when you think you've found a match. Either you'll see that it's double-counting some square or it's including some points which do not form a square.

Comment: OP's solution is (cleverly) O(N**2 ln N) so this doesn't really fly.

Comment: @QuestionC: My second method is O(n^2 log n). I provided the first method, which is O(n^3), as a simpler solution which some may prefer to implement. Also note that neither of my methods takes square roots at any point.

Comment: @Charles I edited the topic. I put the output and the expected output. I 'm not counting fake squares. I'm counting the same square 3 times because of the sides i think. Sorry i think i did not understand the method you gave

Comment: @NewYear: You should only search for B in the region after A, C in the region after B, and D in the region after C. If you do this you won't be able to have duplicates.

Comment: Thats a O(N^3) solution, not what I want... Thats a very slow solution.

Comment: @NewYear: My second method is O(n^2 log n). You iterate through A, B pairs and search for C (at most twice) and D (at most once).

Comment: Thats my solution, what i want to reach. Problem is: I can not find a way to calculate C and D when the square is in all ways possible, check the images i have been posted.

Comment: I'll edit this into my answer if it isn't clear to you.

Comment: I realy can get it the part "and check if C1 (resp., C2) is on the list following B. If so, call it C and check if". All i want is an answer like @jarod42 but with the right calculation.Sorry for not understanding, would you mind to right some code. I'm having realy difficulties. Sorry about that

Comment: @NewYear: My algorithm is correct and fast. But I've put a lot of work into this question already, especially for the negative score it's earned me thus far.

Comment: If your "help" term is just like you last comment, i just want to thank you.